# How to click on object in title with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tooltip

I have a html form that have a jQuery plugin tooltip

```
<div href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='<?php echo "admin/".$item['img'] ?>'  width='70' height='70' /><a  style='float:left;margin:19px auto;'  class='button topmenu'>ارسال پیام</a>"><img src="<?php echo "admin/".$item['img'] ?>" alt="user" width="70" height="70"  /></div>
```

in this code in title I have a link with

```
<a></a>
```

I want when click to this link a popup windows show but I can't do this with this code

```
$(".tooltip title").click(function()
{
$("#login-box").fadeIn(300);
return false;
});
```

how can I call this link in title ?
when mouse go in 1 number 2 is show I want when I click in link in no 2 my form is apear ..

[image]

Comment: no it doesnt work .. when mouse go on tooltip is open in this is a link i want when i click in this do

Comment: Can you prepare a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

please try the following:

```
$(".topmenu").click(function() {
    $("#login-box").fadeIn(300);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful to surround the title HTML attribute with double quotes and use single quotes for the php code. For example:

`"<img src="<?php echo 'admin/'.$item['img'] ?>"`

instead of:

`"<img src='<?php echo "admin/".$item['img'] ?>'`